# Google Cloud persistent disk pricing not prorated like Amazon EBS?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gce-persistent-disk

Is GCP persistent disk pricing prorated for short term use like retrieving data from a backup snapshot?

Pricing for GCP balanced storage is $0.1 per GB per month.
If I create a 100GB disk for 1 day only in a 30 days month. Will I be billed for:

(1) 0.1 * 100 = $10?

Or

(2) 0.1 * 100 / 30 days = $0.33?

With Amazon EBS it seems to be (2) according to [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/). But according to GCE pricing, although not clear, Google seems more like (1).

Comment: This site isn't really the right place to ask this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [disk pricing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/disks-image-pricing)  is always prorated. However, you can use the [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) to get a good estimate of any product pricing.